# Finding a value within an array of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm familiar with using `in_array` when I want to find if a value is in an array.

Is there a similar, and efficient approach, to return `true` or `false` if a value is within an array of arrays?

```
$example = array(
   array( 'small', 6789), 
   array( 'blue', 'duck', 'music'), 
   array( 1000, 'gems' ) 
);
```

In the above example I would want to return `true` if I were looking for 'blue'.

I know I can loop through the array and use `in_array`, but I'm sure I'm missing an easier (and faster) approach.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to change the data structure you're using to store this information I don't think there is a better way to check for an individual string than looping through each array and using in_array for each one.

Remember an array is an object in memory. The outer array is storing pointers to each of the arrays inside it, it does not have direct access to their contents.